# Prove if there exists $h\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $|u(x)| +|u(x)|^{p-1}\le h(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $s\in (0, 1/2)$ and $p\in (2, 2^*_s)$, where $2^*_s= 2/(1-2s)$. Let $q\in [1, 2^*_s)$ and let $u$ be a function such that there exists $l\in L^q(\mathbb R)$ satisfying
$|u(x)|\le l(x)$ a.e. in $\mathbb R$.

The question is: does $h\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ exist such that
$$|u(x)| +|u(x)|^{p-1}\le h(x)?$$

It seems true to me for $|u|$ but I am not sure if it is the same for the power $|u|^{p-1}$.
Anyone could help with that?

Comment: It is same as asking if $|u(x)| +|u(x)|^{p-1}$ is integable which is false because $u$ need not be integrable.

Comment: Is it for all $q$, or just there exists a $q$?

Comment: @LL3.14 I edited the question.

Comment: @geetha290krm $u$ need not be integrable, but it is dominated by an integrable function.

Comment: For a measurable function $f$ the conidtion $|f| \le g$ for some  integrable function $g$  is equivalent to the condition that $f$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Take $u \in L^{q}$ such that $u \notin L^{1}$. Take $l=u$. If your conlcusion holds then $\int |u|\leq \int h <\infty$, which is a contradiction.